# GeoServer get GeoJSON from AJAX issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonp, geoserver

I am using GeoServer version 2.2.5, and what I try to do is making a AJAX call to get the json string from the output GeoJSON url, for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sf/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=sf:archsites&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=json
```

the javascript I used is like this:

```
    var processJSON = function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    };
    function init() {
        //geojson url
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sf/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=sf:archsites&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=json&&format_options=callback:processJSON";

        //execuate ajax request to get data
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'processJSON' 
        });

    }
```

I am pretty sure that this method works, because I can get the json object from the url which is from GeoServer version 2.2.4. But it just doesn't work for GeoServer 2.2.5 and later. I read somewhere that says "JSONP support has been disabled by default since it is perceived as a security issue." But I have no idea how to make it work.

Can anyone give me some suggestion on this?

Thank you very much